# Checking a file of words for those that can be formed with a given set of letters: strange result?

Tags: python, string, list, file

I’m quite new to python and am getting some strange results, surely due to a basic error on my part…

Basically, in Python 3.x, I must define a function (`best_words(ltr_set,word_file)`) that takes a set of letters (a list of characters) and searches a .txt file of words (1 word per line) for those that can be formed with those letters.

I first defined a function that checks if a given word can be made from a given set of letters. The word to be checked must be fed into this function as a list of characters (lsta), so it can be checked against the set of letters available (lstb):

```
def can_make_lsta_wrd_frm_lstb(lsta,lstb):
    result = True
    i = 0
    while i < len(lsta) and result == True:
        if lsta[i] in lstb:
            lstb.remove(lsta[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            result = False
    return result
```

I also defined a function that takes any given string and converts it into a list of it's characters:

```
def lst(string):
    ls = []
    for c in string:
        ls.append(c)
    return ls
```

The idea behind the main `best_words` function is therefore to take a given set of letters and apply the above function to every line in a file of words, with the aim of filtering down to only those that can be made from the letters available...

```
def best_words(ltr_set, word_file):

    possible_words = []

    f = open(word_file)
    lines = f.readlines()

    i = 0
    while i < len(lines):
        lines[i] = lines[i].strip('\n')
        i+=1

    for item in lines:
        if can_make_lsta_wrd_frm_lstb(lst(item),ltr_set):
            possible_words.append(item)

    return possible_words
```

However, I keep getting an unexpected result, as if a loop is not continued as it should be…

For instance, if I take a file short_dictionnary.txt with the following words:

```
AA
AAS
ABACA
ABACAS
ABACOST
ABACOSTS
ABACULE
ABACULES
ABAISSA
ABAISSABLE
```

and call the function:

```
best_words([‘A’,’C’,’B’,’A’,’S’,’A’], “short_dictionnary.txt”)
```

The possible_words list is comprised solely of “AA”…whilst AAS, ABACA and ABACAS could also be formed…

If anyone can see what’s going on, their input be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're passing in `lstb` and the calling `lstb.remove` the list inside `can_make...` is the same list as `letter_set`.  So you shrink `letter_set` whenever you call `lstb.remove`

Comment: You're modifying the list of letters with `lstb.remove(lsta[i])`. So the next time you call the function, it's missing all the letters from the previous word.

Comment: Also, you specified that you must pass a set of letters, however you are passing a list.  There **is** a difference.

Comment: You should make a copy of `lstb` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I've understood the error!

Answer (score 0):

I would convert `letter_set` to a `Counter` and then for each letter in possible word, check that there are enough of that letter in `letter_set` to make that word. You're also leaking file references.

```
from collections import Counter

def can_make_word(c, word):
    return all(c[letter]>=count for letter, count in Counter(word).most_common())

def best_words(ltr_set, word_file):

    possible_words = []
    c = Counter(ltr_set)

    with open(word_file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

    for item in lines:
        if can_make_word(c, item):
            possible_words.append(item)

    return possible_words
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I now understand what I had to do!

I essentially needed to ensure the original ltr_set wasn't modified; so this was achieved by making a simple copy. I don't know if answering my own question is of any use (I'm quite new to this forum), but here's the corrected `can_make...` function should anyone find it useful for resolving a similar issue:

```
def can_make_lsta_wrd_frm_lstb(lsta,lstb):
    lstb_copy = lstb[:]
    result = True
    i = 0
    while i < len(lsta) and result == True:
        if lsta[i] in lstb_copy:
            lstb_copy.remove(lsta[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            result = False
    return result
```